# Where does Flash do the counting? Server - Client side?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'd like to know if I have downloaded (loaded to my computer) any big flash game like Evony or so where does it do the counting? I mean in the flash files which I have dowloaded to my computer, will there be the counting functions where it counts everything like attacking, defensing, etc.

The above is just an example, it could be any big flash game. The question remains the same. Where does these games do the counting part. It is in those flash files or it is somewhere else on their server which I can't see?

Comment: Yeah, what @Rizzla said. This question cannot be answered definitively. Maybe you should clarify what it is you want to know... or if you were just thinking in general terms the answer from Rizzla should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

That depends of the game and the developers that make them. As rule of thumb for network games is that everything that needs to be stored or process in any way, like counting - is to do it on the server. The Flash player is considered insecure, because it can be easily hacked, so every action in the game that is significant needs to be executed on server, because they are harder to hack.

Again, this really depends on the choices of the developers, how they will structure the game. So you can't really know unless they tell you or you hack the flash code and see it for yourself.